# GDAL code does not work on anaconda interpreter

Tags: gdal, anaconda, typeerror

I wrote a code that projects a raster to a new coordinate system.

```
from osgeo import gdal

filename = r"C:\Users\rsl\Desktop\New folder\SN228122015_mosaic.tif"
input_raster = gdal.Open(filename)
output_raster = r"C:\Users\rsl\Desktop\New folder\SN228122015_mosaic_p.tif"
gdal.Warp(output_raster,input_raster,dstSRS='EPSG:4326')
```

The code works great on pycharm when the interpreter is OSGEO, but when I run it when the interpreter is anaconda (like on jupyter notebook), I get this message error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9021d776efc4> in <module>()
      4 input_raster = gdal.Open(filename)
      5 output_raster = r"C:\Users\rsl\Desktop\New folder\SN228122015_mosaic_p.tif"
----> 6 gdal.Warp(output_raster,input_raster,dstSRS='EPSG:4326')
      7 

C:\Users\rsl\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.pyc in Warp(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSOrSrcDSTab, **kwargs)
    547 
    548     if _is_str_or_unicode(destNameOrDestDS):
--> 549         return wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)
    550     else:
    551         return wrapper_GDALWarpDestDS(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)

TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALWarpDestName', argument 4 of type 'GDALWarpAppOptions *'
```

How can I make my code to work on the anaconda environment?

Comment: Are the `gdal` versions the same? You can access that information from the interpreter using `gdal.VersionInfo()`

Comment: @user88484 Did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: @Binks - it was so long ago... I don't remember what I did back then, but these days I just use `rasterio` for all raster manipulations.

Comment: @user88484 Thanks for getting back to me. Yeah, I've used `rasterio`, but have found `gdal` to processes a bit faster (for my pipeline). I did find a solution that worked for me though. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472933/pyinstaller-executable-fails)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here, I [found](https://github.com/developmentseed/sentinel-util/issues/2) that we need to set the `GDAL_DATA` environment variable.

e.g. `GDAL_DATA=C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\data\gdal`

Answer (score 0):

If setting the `GDAL_DATA` environment variable does not work then you may have to replace `dstSRS='EPSG:4326'` with `gdal.WarpOptions(dstSRS='EPSG:4326')` to get rid of the error that you are getting. You are supplying an keyword object where a `gdal.WarpOptions` object is needed.

Check out the docs for more information: https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#WarpOptions